# What is the difference between Java EE and Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jakarta-ee

I like to know the difference between Asp.net and Java EE.

Comment: This is such a broad question. Would you mind clarify better what you're interested in?

Comment: Agreed - you're going to have to be more specific. Since you obviously don't think "Java vs .NET" is a good answer (although it isn't incorrect), what *are* you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J2EE (since 3 years to be called "[Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition)") is a bit broader than ASP.NET (that was an *understatement*). You can best compare "[ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET)" with "[JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces)". They both have the same purposes/capabilities: a component based MVC framework which offers taglibs which are to be used in respectively ASP and JSP pages. The major difference is that ASP.NET is to be runt with [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) "codebehind", while JSF is to be runt with [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) "codebehind".

That's basically all. The one is based on C#, the other is based on Java.

Answer (score 2):

Java and .NET? ahem

Answer (score 1):

You would love working on Java EE ;)